# how to make post request in python

Tags: python, curl

Here is the curl command:

```
curl -H "X-API-TOKEN: <API-TOKEN>" 'http://foo.com/foo/bar' --data #
```

let me explain what goes into data

```
POST /foo/bar
Input (request JSON body)

Name    Type    
title   string  
body    string
```

So, based on this.. I figured:

curl -H "X-API-TOKEN: " 'http://foo.com/foo/bar' --data '{"title":"foobar","body": "This body has both "double" and 'single' quotes"}'

Unfortunately, I am not able to figure that out as well (like curl from cli)
Though I would like to use python to send this request.
How do i do this?

Comment: Have you tried a library called pycurl? It's literally an emulation of curl with the exact same settings and almost the same syntax.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

With the standard Python `httplib` and `urllib` libraries you can do

```
import httplib, urllib

headers = {'X-API-TOKEN': 'your_token_here'}
payload = "'title'='value1'&'name'='value2'"

conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("heise.de")
conn.request("POST", "", payload, headers)
response = conn.getresponse()

print response
```

or if you want to use the nice HTTP library called ["Requests"](http://docs.python-requests.org).

```
import requests

headers = {'X-API-TOKEN': 'your_token_here'}
payload = {'title': 'value1', 'name': 'value2'}

r = requests.post("http://foo.com/foo/bar", data=payload, headers=headers)
```

Comment: I used  both and I prefer *Requests* that others, it's more simple.

Comment: Just for notice, requests provides built-in function for json response body parsing:

    respJsonDict = r.json()

Comment: In the requests example it should say `json=payload`, not `data=payload` if payload is a json struct, like here...

Comment: In the case of the request library, it is worth mentioning that print (r) will return the HTTP response 200 meaning all is ok if you want the JSON response text you must print (r.txt)